# how to define user role relationship in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-manager, user-account

I created the user 'Auser' in geoserver and define the roles Aread, Aadmin and Awrite where Awrite is inheriting the rights of Aread. but when I click Auser to pick the roles from service it gives me only default- how will I configure this? Essentially My roleservice.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<roleRegistry xmlns="http://www.geoserver.org/security/roles" version="1.0">
<roleList>
<role id="admin"/>
<role id="read"/>
<role id="write" parentID="read"/>
</roleList>
<userList/>
<groupList/>
</roleRegistry>
```

instead of the one given under default

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<roleRegistry xmlns="http://www.geoserver.org/security/roles" version="1.0">
<roleList>
<role id="ADMIN"/>
<role id="GROUP_ADMIN"/>
</roleList>
<userList>
<userRoles username="admin">
<roleRef roleID="ADMIN"/>
</userRoles>
</userList>
<groupList>
<groupRoles groupname="Role_administrator"/>
</groupList>
</roleRegistry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be controlled with security setting by changing the active role [service](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/security/settings.html#active-role-service).